# Publish fitness course datapoints locations in Android using Open Graph API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, geolocation

I am working on an Android fitness application, I am trying on publish activity datapoints location on Facebook using Open Graph API. I used the following code, it published only `location1`, but not other locations added to the list.

```
public void shareWorkout (View v){
    if (FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(getApplicationContext(), FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG)) {
        OpenGraphObject course = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost(null);
        course.setType("fitness.course");
        course.setTitle("Walking Course");
        course.setUrl("http://samples.ogp.me/136756249803614");
        course.setDescription("walked a course");

        GraphObject location1 = GraphObject.Factory.create();
        location1.setProperty("latitude", 31.90592568833381f);
        location1.setProperty("longitude", 35.20052916370332f);
        location1.setProperty("altitude", 0.0f);

        GraphObject location2 = GraphObject.Factory.create();
        location2.setProperty("latitude", 31.912331976927817f);
        location2.setProperty("longitude", 35.205821581184864f);
        location2.setProperty("altitude", 0.0f);

        List<GraphObject> locations = new ArrayList<GraphObject>();
        locations.add(location1);
        locations.add(location2);

        GraphObject metrics = GraphObject.Factory.create();
        metrics.setProperty("location", locations);

        course.getData().setProperty("metrics", metrics);

        OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
        action.setProperty("course", course);

        FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this,
        action, "fitness.walks", "course").build();            
        uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
    }
}
```

Comment: fitness.course doesn't take an array of locations. Are you perhaps trying to set the fitness:metrics:location?

Comment: yes exactly that's what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

I also trying to share a course on facebook.

Like the [facebook Submission Criteria](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/fitness#criteria) mentioned you should include as many appropriate metrics available (pace, geo-points, distance).

So for each new location you have to create a new metric object, with the location, a timestamp, distance and pace and add this metrics-Array to the metric-Property.

Here is my working example:

```
private void shareWorkout(Location[] locations) {
    NumberFormat doubleFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
    doubleFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(6);
    doubleFormat.setMaximumIntegerDigits(3);
    doubleFormat.setGroupingUsed(false);

    OpenGraphObject course = OpenGraphObject.Factory
            .createForPost("fitness.course");
    course.setTitle("Sample Course");
    List<GraphObject> metrics = new ArrayList<GraphObject>();
    Location prevLocation = null;

    for (Location location : locations) {
        GraphObject metric = GraphObject.Factory.create();
        double distance = calcDistance(prevLocation, location);
        double speed = location.getSpeed() * LocationUtils.MS_TO_KMH;
        double pace = speed == 0 ? 0.0 : 60.0 / speed;
        metric.setProperty("location:longitude",
                doubleFormat.format(location.getLongitude()));
        metric.setProperty("location:latitude",
                doubleFormat.format(location.getLatitude()));
        metric.setProperty("location:altitude",
                doubleFormat.format(location.getAltitude()));
        metric.setProperty("timestamp",
                StringUtils.formatDateTimeIso8601(location.getTime()));
        metric.setProperty("distance:value", doubleFormat.format(distance));
        metric.setProperty("distance:units", "km");
        metric.setProperty("pace:value", doubleFormat.format(pace));
        metric.setProperty("pace:units", "s/m");
        metrics.add(metric);
        prevLocation = location;
    }
    GraphObject courseData = course.getData();
    courseData.setProperty("metrics", metrics);
    courseData.setProperty("distance:value", calcTime(locations));
    courseData.setProperty("distance:units", "min");
    courseData.setProperty("distance:value",
            doubleFormat.format(calcTotalDistance(locations)));
    courseData.setProperty("distance:units", "km");
    OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory
            .create(OpenGraphAction.class);
    action.setProperty("course", course);
    action.setType("fitness.walks");

    RequestBatch requestBatch = new RequestBatch();
    Request request = Request.newPostOpenGraphActionRequest(
            Session.getActiveSession(), action, shareCallback);
    requestBatch.add(request);
    requestBatch.executeAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't upvote this enough, as this fixes the problem, is way better than Facebook's sample codes and also teaches how to handle objects and properties.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue while updating from Facebook SDK 3.x to 4.1.

In my situation, I already had all the fitness metadata on the target web url (created using the reference https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/fitness), the problem was that documentation about Sharing (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android#advanced) was a bit misleading. After few tries I've found that `fitness:course` can also be passed as URL, not only as `ShareGraphObject`:

```
ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
            .setActionType("fitness.runs")
            .putString("fitness:course", url)
            .build();

ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
            .setPreviewPropertyName("fitness:course")
            .setAction(action)
            .build();
```

Than call the

```
if (shareDialog.canShow(ShareOpenGraphContent.class)) {
    shareDialog.show(content);
}
```

Hope this helps!